# Find the volume common to sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2$ and the cylinder $x^2+y^2<ax$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Find the volume common to sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2<1$ and the cylinder $x^2+y^2<ax$

I set up the following integral :

$$I=2\cdot \iiint_{z=0}^{\sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2}} dz\,dy\,dz = 2\cdot\iint_E\sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2} \, dy\,dx$$ where $E:x^2+y^2=ax$

Now under polar coordinates 
$E:r=a\cos(\theta)$

and so $0\leq r \leq a\cos(\theta)$ and $-\pi/2\leq \theta \leq \pi/2$

$$I= 2\cdot\int_{\theta=-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\,\int_{r=0}^{a\cos(\theta)} \sqrt{a^2-r^2}\,r\,dr\,d\theta=2\cdot (1/2)\cdot(2/3)\int_{\theta=-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}a^3\cdot(1-\sin^3(\theta))d\theta = \frac{2a^3}{3}\cdot\{\int_{\theta=-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} d\theta - \int_{\theta=-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin^3(\theta)d\theta\} = \frac{2\pi a^3}{3}$$

However answer given to me is $$\frac{2a^3}{3}\cdot(\pi - \frac43)$$

Where am I making the mistake? Or is it the case that the answer given to me is incorrect?

Comment: Use `$$\begin{align} a&=b\\ &=c\end{align}$$` for $$\begin{align} a&=b\\ &=c\end{align}$$

Comment: The definite integral of $\sin^3\theta$ from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2} = \frac{2}{3}$

Comment: @PhilH But $\theta $ varies
 $-\pi/2 $ to $\pi/2 $ and $\sin^3(\theta ) $ being odd, its integral will be zero.

Comment: @PhilH Although, the answer does match when $\theta$ is taken to vary from $0$ to $\pi/2$ and the integral is multiplied by 2 (**symmetry? But how?**). But I don't see how  $\theta$ from $-\pi/2 $ to $\pi/2 $ $\Leftrightarrow $ $\theta$ from $0$ to $\pi/2$ in this particular question.

Comment: for unit sphere, why do you have the upper bound for $z$ as $\sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2}$ ?

Comment: This is not it, you've made an error in simplifying $(1-\sin^2\theta)^{3/2}$. This is not $(1-\sin^3\theta)$. You should end up with $a^3 -a^3\cos^3\theta$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$I= 2\cdot\int_{\theta=-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\,\int_{r=0}^{a\cos(\theta)} \sqrt{a^2-r^2}\,r\,dr\,d\theta=2\cdot (1/2)\cdot(2/3)\int_{\theta=-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}a^3\cdot(1-\color{red}{|\sin^3(\theta)|})d\theta$$

Specifically,

$$\int_0^{a\cos t} \sqrt{a^2 - r^2}rdr = \frac{1}{2}\int_{a^2\sin^2t}^{a^2} u^{1/2}dr = \frac{a^3}{3}\left(1-(\sin^2t)^{3/2}\right)= \frac{a^3}{3}\left(1-|\sin^3t|\right)$$

The rest follows as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $a<1/2$, here's the proper integral:

$$\int\limits_{x=0}^a \int\limits_{y=0}^\sqrt{x(a - x)} \int\limits_{z=0}^\sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2} 4\ dx\ dy\ dz$$